# Issues with web application

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sql, xml

The previous programmer left the website in pretty unusable state, and I am having difficulty modifying anything. I am new to web design so I don't know whether my skills are a mismatch to this kind of job or is it normal in the real industry to have websites like these

1. The Home page includes three frames
2. Each of these frames have their own javascript functions ( between `<head>`, and also call other common javascript functions (using `<script src=..>`
3. Excessive usage of `document.all` - in fact the elements are referred or accessed by document.all only.
4. Excessive usage of XSLT and Web Services - Though I know that using Web Services is generally considered a good design choice - is there any other way I can consume these services other than using xslt. For example, the menu is created using the data returned by a web method.
5. Every `<div>`, `<td>` and every other element has an id, and these id's are manipulated by the javascript functions, and then some appropriate web service and the xslt files are loaded based on these..
6. From the security perspective, he used `T-SQL's for xml auto` for most of the data that is returned by the web service - is it a good choice from the security standpoint to expose the table names and column names to the end user??

I am a lot confused about the state of the application itself. Should I learn about the intricacies that he has developed and continue working on it, or should I start rewriting everything? What I am perplexed a lot is the lack of alternatives - and whether this is the common way web projects are handled in the real world or was it an exception?

Any suggestions, any pointers are welcome. Thanks

Comment: It does not sound to me as if this is using the asp.net framework as it was intended. So if my opinion means anything I would strongly consider another architecture.

Comment: @Klaus.. true. It's year 2010 (with 4.0 framework released ), and the application is still in ASP.Net 1.1.4322!! Thanks for the advice, I'am thinking about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not acceptable in this industry that people keep writing un-maintainable code.

My advice to you is to go up the chain and convince everyone that this needs to be rewritten. If they question you, find an external consultant with relevant web development skills to review the application (for 1 day).

Keeping this website as-is, because it 'works' is like keeping a working model Ford-T car on today's highways, very dangerous. Security and maintenance costs are likely the most persuading topics to convince anyone against keeping this site 'as-is'.

Next, get yourself trained, it will pay off if you can rewrite this application knowing the basics. Todays technology (asp.net MVC) allows you to implement core business value faster than trying to maintain this unconventionally written app.

Comment: It is not a wise idea to rewrite the code from scratch. Here's one good blog post from Joel Spolsky: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000069.html
It is always better option to refactor the code then to rewrite it from scratch.

Comment: I think also restrain is in order here. It is very difficult to read code almost always. Just because you cannot understand it does not mean there is anything wrong with it :)

Comment: Given the context: 1) the developer left + 2) unstable website + 3) unexperienced new developer + 4) .net 1.1 ??
 a rewrite from scratch it the best option.
Refactoring such a site would require a highly skilled professional. The high risk of breaking the site and spending more time and money attempting to get it to a maintable state would surely break anyone's morale to continue to develop this site. So to this poster my answer stands:

Attempt in all possible ways to have business see the obvious value in building the site from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

Tough spot for an inexperienced developer (or any) to be left in. I think you have a few hard weeks a head of you where you really need to read up on the technologies involved to get a better understanding of them and what is best practice. You will also need to really dig down into the existing code to understand how it all hangs together.

When you done all that you really need to think about your options. Usually re-writing something from scratch (especially if it actually works) is a bad idea. This obviously depend on the size of the project, for a smaller projects with only a couple of thousand lines of code it might be OK. When looking at someone elses code it is also easy to overlook that all that weird shit going on could actually be fixes for valid requirements. Things often start out looking neat, but then the real words comes visiting.

You will need to present the business with time estimates for re-writing to see if that is an option at all, but I'm guessing you will need to accept the way things are and do your best with what you have. Maybe you could gradually improves things.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend moving the project to MVC3 and rewriting the XSLT portions to function using views and/or partial views with MVC. The Razor model binding syntax is very clean and should be able to quickly cleave out the dirty XSLT code and be left with just the model properties you would need.

I would then have those web services invoked from MVC serverside and for you to deserialize the object results into real objects (or even just use straight XQuery or Json traversing to directly pull stuff out for your model) and bind those to your views.

This could be a rather gargantuan leap for technology at your company though. Some places have aversion to change.

Comment: Thanks for referring those technologies. used a little bit MVC but never heard Razor.. and never used XQuery though.. but will keep myself abreast. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess this was written 6-7 years ago, and hacked on since then.  Every project accumulates a certain amount of bubble gum and duct tape.  Sounds like this one's got it bad.  I suggest breaking this up into bite size chunks.  I assume that the site is actually working right now?  So you don't want to break anything, the "business" often thinks "it was working just fine when the last guy was here."

Get a feel for your biggest pain points for maintaining the project, and what you'll get the biggest wins from fixing.  a rewrite is great, if you have the time and support.  But if it's a complex site, there's a lot to be said for a mature application.  Mature in the sense that it fulfills the business needs, not that it's good code.

Also, working on small parts will get you better acquainted with the project and the business needs, so when you start the rewrite you'll have a better perspective.